# Display multiple results using an Nested if statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Display multiple results using an Nested if statement.

Is there a way to display multiple results from a nested if statement? or how do i change it to do so.

I am currently using:

```
=IF(H3="Yes",D3,IF(AD3="Yes",E3,IF(AZ3="Yes",F3,"None")))
```

If more than one is yes I would like to display both results.
Would I need to create a long IF(AND(  statement including all of the possible outcomes or does someone know a quicker way ??

Comment: You have to write the IF condition where both of condition are true (using AND) as you suggested. There is not others way without using VBA-

Comment: Thanks, I have done

=IF(H3="Yes",D3,IF(AD3="Yes",E3,IF(AZ3="Yes",F3,IF(AND(H3="Yes",AD3="Yes",D3&E3),IF(AND(H3="Yes",AZ3="Yes",D3&F3),IF(AND(AD3="Yes",AZ3="Yes",E3&F3),"None"))))))

However It does not show both cells if they are both yes, can you see anything wrong?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in your formula is incorrect.

**First** you need to check all the **AND**s and then you can check for the single occurrences. So, your formula should start with

```
=if(AND(H3="Y‌​es";AD3="Yes";AZ3="Yes");D3&E3&F3);if(and(H3="Y‌​es";AD3="Yes");D3&E3...
```

and towards the end of your formula you are adding the single checks

```
if(H3="Yes",D3,if(AD3="Yes",E3,...
```